# Mod $p$ irreducibility test proof question

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

This is the statement of the mod $p$ irreducibility theorem.

> Let $p$ be a prime and suppose that $f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ with deg
>   $f(x) \ge 1$. Let $f'(x)$ be the polynomial in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ obtained
>   from $f(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients of $f(x)$ modulo $p$. If
>   $f'(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_p$ and deg $f (x) =$ deg $f'(x)$,
>   then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

I'm confused about the proof of this theorem at the bolded text.

If $f(x)$ is reducible
over $\Bbb Q$, then $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ with $g(x), h(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$, and both
$g(x)$ and $h(x)$ have degree less than that of $f(x)$. Let $f'(x),g'(x)$ , and $h'(x)$ be the polynomials obtained from $f(x), g(x)$, and $h(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients modulo $p$. Since $deg f(x) = degf'(x)$ , we have deg $g'(x) \le$ deg $g(x) \lt$ deg$f'(x)$ and deg $h'(x) \le $ deg $h(x) \lt$ deg $f'(x)$. **But $f'(x) = g'(x)h'(x)$, and this contradicts our assumption that $f'(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_p$.**

Where is the contradiction here?

Comment: Not following.  if you've produced a valid factoring of $f'(x)$ then $f'(x)$ can't be irreducible.  Not a big fan of the notation though...$f'$ is normally reserved for the derivative.

Comment: But how can I be sure that $g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ are both not units in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$?

Comment: Well, if both were units then $f'$ would also be a unit.  If just one were a unit, the other would have degree=degree $f'$

Comment: @Oliver G: If you consider any integral domain $R$, then in general $\partial(fg) = \partial f + \partial g$ in $R[x]$, whence if $f$ had a multiplicative inverse $g$ in $R[x]$ then $fg = 1 \Rightarrow f \neq 0, g \neq 0$, and $0 = \partial(fg) = \partial f + \partial g \Rightarrow$ since $\partial f \geq 0$ and $\partial g \geq = 0$, so $\partial f = \partial g = 0 \therefore f$ is a non-zero constant in $R[X]$. Thus the group of .... (cont.)

Comment: .... units in $R[x]$ equals (as constants) the group of units in $R$. Thus for $p$ prime, $g'$ and $h'$ both units in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ implies $f'$ constant $\Rightarrow f$ constant $\Rightarrow f$ irreducible. From the identity $\partial(fg) = \partial f + \partial g$ for an integral domain we can similarly deduce $R[x]$ is an integral domain for any integral domain $R$ - and thus cancellation is applicable in $R[x]$ which is often helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The theorem says that:

> If $f'(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ and $\deg f'(x)=\deg f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

The proof goes by contradiction, by assuming there exists a reducible $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that $\deg f'(x)=\deg f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$. The proof shows that then necessarily $f'(x)$ is reducible in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$, because $f'(x)=g'(x)h'(x)$, a contradiction.

Note that if $\deg f'(x)=\deg f(x)$ and $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then $\deg g'(x)=\deg g(x)$ and $\deg h'(x)=\deg h(x)$. So $g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ are not units in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ because $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are not units in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Referring to the last sentence:  But how can you be sure they're not units in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$?  Couldn't terms be eliminated because of the $p$ mod and reduced to constants?

Comment: Does the converse hold?