# Irreducible Polynomials mod p

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have this theorem in my algebra book but I cannot seem to come up nor find a proof that is not done by contradiction. Can you please help me? Maybe give me a hint ? I would really like to have a clue on how to start the proof by assuming that our polynomial is, in fact, irreducible over $\Bbb Z_p$ .

I found the same question and I will leave the link here: [Mod $p$ irreducibility test proof question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925120/mod-p-irreducibility-test-proof-question)

> Let $p$ be a prime and suppose that $f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ with deg
> $f(x) \ge 1$. Let $f'(x)$ be the polynomial in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ obtained
> from $f(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients of $f(x)$ modulo $p$. If
> $f'(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_p$ and deg $f (x) =$ deg $f'(x)$,
> then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: What's wrong with a proof by contradiction?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was another one I could have a look at......the one I saw is using the counter-reciprocal.

Comment: The usual proof is a straightforward proof by contrapositive, and the assumption you start with is that $f(x)$ is *reducible* over $\mathbb{Q}$; then you deduce that $f(x) \bmod p$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: yes that is the one I saw. Well thank you, I guess I am going to accept that is the "only" way to do it :)

Comment: "yes that is the one I saw. Well thank you, I guess I am going to accept that is the "only" way to do it".  A proof by contrapositive is *not* a proof by contradiction, and it *is* direct.  The only way to prove something is irreducible is to prove it is not reducible and a *direct* way to do that is to note it is only reducible under conditions that don't apply.  That is a *direct* proof by contrapositive and that is *exactly* what the described proof does.

Comment: yes that makes sense, thank you !